# ¿como puedo insertar datos de un xml a mysql con php?

Tags: php, mysql, xml

lo que pasa esque genere un .bat que que recopilara los datos de mi cpu y los datos me los gererara en un formato xml con el siguiente codigo

```
wmic cpu get /all /format:rawxml.xsl >cpu.xml
```

y me genero el siguiente xml

```
<COMMAND SEQUENCENUM="1" ISSUEDFROM="IVAN-PC" STARTTIME="07-29-2017T18:09:21" EVERYCOUNT="0"><REQUEST><COMMANDLINE>  cpu get /all /format:rawxml.xsl </COMMANDLINE>
<COMMANDLINECOMPONENTS><NODELIST><NODE>IVAN-PC</NODE>
</NODELIST>
</COMMANDLINECOMPONENTS>
<CONTEXT><NAMESPACE>root\cimv2</NAMESPACE>
<ROLE>root\cli</ROLE>
<IMPLEVEL>IMPERSONATE</IMPLEVEL>
<AUTHLEVEL>PKTPRIVACY</AUTHLEVEL>
<LOCALE>ms_c0a</LOCALE>
<PRIVILEGES>ENABLE</PRIVILEGES>
<TRACE>OFF</TRACE>
<RECORD>N/A</RECORD>
<INTERACTIVE>OFF</INTERACTIVE>
<FAILFAST>OFF</FAILFAST>
<OUTPUT>STDOUT</OUTPUT>
<APPEND>STDOUT</APPEND>
<USER>N/A</USER>
<AGGREGATE>ON</AGGREGATE>
</CONTEXT>
</REQUEST>
<RESULTS NODE="IVAN-PC"><CIM><INSTANCE CLASSNAME="Win32_Processor"><PROPERTY NAME="AddressWidth" CLASSORIGIN="CIM_Processor" TYPE="uint16"><VALUE>64</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="Architecture" CLASSORIGIN="Win32_Processor" TYPE="uint16"><VALUE>9</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="Availability" CLASSORIGIN="CIM_LogicalDevice" TYPE="uint16"><VALUE>3</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="Caption" CLASSORIGIN="CIM_ManagedSystemElement" TYPE="string"><VALUE>AMD64 Family 16 Model 6 Stepping 3</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="ConfigManagerErrorCode" CLASSORIGIN="CIM_LogicalDevice" PROPAGATED="true" TYPE="uint32"></PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="ConfigManagerUserConfig" CLASSORIGIN="CIM_LogicalDevice" PROPAGATED="true" TYPE="boolean"></PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="CpuStatus" CLASSORIGIN="Win32_Processor" TYPE="uint16"><VALUE>1</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="CreationClassName" CLASSORIGIN="CIM_LogicalDevice" TYPE="string"><VALUE>Win32_Processor</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="CurrentClockSpeed" CLASSORIGIN="CIM_Processor" TYPE="uint32"><VALUE>1700</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="CurrentVoltage" CLASSORIGIN="Win32_Processor" TYPE="uint16"><VALUE>11</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="DataWidth" CLASSORIGIN="CIM_Processor" TYPE="uint16"><VALUE>64</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="Description" CLASSORIGIN="CIM_ManagedSystemElement" TYPE="string"><VALUE>AMD64 Family 16 Model 6 Stepping 3</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="DeviceID" CLASSORIGIN="CIM_LogicalDevice" TYPE="string"><VALUE>CPU0</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="ErrorCleared" CLASSORIGIN="CIM_LogicalDevice" PROPAGATED="true" TYPE="boolean"></PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="ErrorDescription" CLASSORIGIN="CIM_LogicalDevice" PROPAGATED="true" TYPE="string"></PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="ExtClock" CLASSORIGIN="Win32_Processor" TYPE="uint32"><VALUE>200</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="Family" CLASSORIGIN="CIM_Processor" TYPE="uint16"><VALUE>237</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="InstallDate" CLASSORIGIN="CIM_ManagedSystemElement" PROPAGATED="true" TYPE="datetime"></PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="L2CacheSize" CLASSORIGIN="Win32_Processor" TYPE="uint32"><VALUE>1024</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="L2CacheSpeed" CLASSORIGIN="Win32_Processor" PROPAGATED="true" TYPE="uint32"></PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="L3CacheSize" CLASSORIGIN="Win32_Processor" TYPE="uint32"><VALUE>0</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="L3CacheSpeed" CLASSORIGIN="Win32_Processor" TYPE="uint32"><VALUE>0</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="LastErrorCode" CLASSORIGIN="CIM_LogicalDevice" PROPAGATED="true" TYPE="uint32"></PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="Level" CLASSORIGIN="Win32_Processor" TYPE="uint16"><VALUE>16</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="LoadPercentage" CLASSORIGIN="CIM_Processor" PROPAGATED="true" TYPE="uint16"></PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="Manufacturer" CLASSORIGIN="Win32_Processor" TYPE="string"><VALUE>AuthenticAMD</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="MaxClockSpeed" CLASSORIGIN="CIM_Processor" TYPE="uint32"><VALUE>1700</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="Name" CLASSORIGIN="CIM_ManagedSystemElement" TYPE="string"><VALUE>AMD Athlon(tm) II Neo K125 Processor</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="NumberOfCores" CLASSORIGIN="Win32_Processor" TYPE="uint32"><VALUE>1</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="NumberOfLogicalProcessors" CLASSORIGIN="Win32_Processor" TYPE="uint32"><VALUE>1</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="OtherFamilyDescription" CLASSORIGIN="CIM_Processor" PROPAGATED="true" TYPE="string"></PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="PNPDeviceID" CLASSORIGIN="CIM_LogicalDevice" PROPAGATED="true" TYPE="string"></PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY.ARRAY NAME="PowerManagementCapabilities" CLASSORIGIN="CIM_LogicalDevice" PROPAGATED="true" TYPE="uint16"></PROPERTY.ARRAY>
<PROPERTY NAME="PowerManagementSupported" CLASSORIGIN="CIM_LogicalDevice" TYPE="boolean"><VALUE>FALSE</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="ProcessorId" CLASSORIGIN="Win32_Processor" TYPE="string"><VALUE>078BFBFF00100F63</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="ProcessorType" CLASSORIGIN="Win32_Processor" TYPE="uint16"><VALUE>3</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="Revision" CLASSORIGIN="Win32_Processor" TYPE="uint16"><VALUE>1539</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="Role" CLASSORIGIN="CIM_Processor" TYPE="string"><VALUE>CPU</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="SocketDesignation" CLASSORIGIN="Win32_Processor" TYPE="string"><VALUE>Socket M2/S1G1</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="Status" CLASSORIGIN="CIM_ManagedSystemElement" TYPE="string"><VALUE>OK</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="StatusInfo" CLASSORIGIN="CIM_LogicalDevice" TYPE="uint16"><VALUE>3</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="Stepping" CLASSORIGIN="CIM_Processor" TYPE="string"><VALUE>3</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="SystemCreationClassName" CLASSORIGIN="CIM_LogicalDevice" TYPE="string"><VALUE>Win32_ComputerSystem</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="SystemName" CLASSORIGIN="CIM_LogicalDevice" TYPE="string"><VALUE>IVAN-PC</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="UniqueId" CLASSORIGIN="CIM_Processor" PROPAGATED="true" TYPE="string"></PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="UpgradeMethod" CLASSORIGIN="CIM_Processor" TYPE="uint16"><VALUE>6</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="Version" CLASSORIGIN="Win32_Processor" TYPE="string"><VALUE>Modelo 6, nivel 3</VALUE>
</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="VoltageCaps" CLASSORIGIN="Win32_Processor" PROPAGATED="true" TYPE="uint32"></PROPERTY>
</INSTANCE>
</CIM>
</RESULTS>
</COMMAND>
```

y lo que quiero es que lo que esta en values llevarlo a un formulario y introducirlos en una base de datos o pasarlo directamente al php alguien sabe como puedo hacer esto?

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza la siguiente funcion

```
function loadXml($str, &$errors = array()){
    $bk = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $xmlDom = simplexml_load_string($str);
    if (!$xmlDom)
        $xmlDom = simplexml_load_string(mb_convert_encoding($str, "UTF-8"));

    if (!$xmlDom){
        foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error){
            $errors[] = "error >> level: {$error->level}, code: {$error->code}, line: {$error->line}, column: {$error->column}, message: {$error->message}";
        }
        libxml_clear_errors();
    }
    libxml_use_internal_errors($bk);

    return $xmlDom;
}
```

Luego haces

```
$xmlDom = loadXml(file_get_contents("cpu.xml"), $errors);
if (!$xmlDom){
    // Manejar los errores aqui. Los errores esta en $errors
}

// Leer las variables xml
$dict = array();
foreach ($xmlDom->xpath("//PROPERTY") as $prop){
    $name = $prop['NAME'];
    $value = (string)$prop->VALUE;
    $dict[$name] = $value;
}

var_dump($dict);
```

Aplicado a tu xml de ejemplo devuelve

```
array(47) {
  ["AddressWidth"]=>
  string(2) "64"
  ["Architecture"]=>
  string(1) "9"
  ["Availability"]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["Caption"]=>
  string(34) "AMD64 Family 16 Model 6 Stepping 3"
  ["ConfigManagerErrorCode"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["ConfigManagerUserConfig"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["CpuStatus"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["CreationClassName"]=>
  string(15) "Win32_Processor"
  ["CurrentClockSpeed"]=>
  string(4) "1700"
  ["CurrentVoltage"]=>
  string(2) "11"
  ["DataWidth"]=>
  string(2) "64"
  ["Description"]=>
  string(34) "AMD64 Family 16 Model 6 Stepping 3"
  ["DeviceID"]=>
  string(4) "CPU0"
  ["ErrorCleared"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["ErrorDescription"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["ExtClock"]=>
  string(3) "200"
  ["Family"]=>
  string(3) "237"
  ["InstallDate"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["L2CacheSize"]=>
  string(4) "1024"
  ["L2CacheSpeed"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["L3CacheSize"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["L3CacheSpeed"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["LastErrorCode"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Level"]=>
  string(2) "16"
  ["LoadPercentage"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Manufacturer"]=>
  string(12) "AuthenticAMD"
  ["MaxClockSpeed"]=>
  string(4) "1700"
  ["Name"]=>
  string(36) "AMD Athlon(tm) II Neo K125 Processor"
  ["NumberOfCores"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["NumberOfLogicalProcessors"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["OtherFamilyDescription"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["PNPDeviceID"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["PowerManagementSupported"]=>
  string(5) "FALSE"
  ["ProcessorId"]=>
  string(16) "078BFBFF00100F63"
  ["ProcessorType"]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["Revision"]=>
  string(4) "1539"
  ["Role"]=>
  string(3) "CPU"
  ["SocketDesignation"]=>
  string(14) "Socket M2/S1G1"
  ["Status"]=>
  string(2) "OK"
  ["StatusInfo"]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["Stepping"]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["SystemCreationClassName"]=>
  string(20) "Win32_ComputerSystem"
  ["SystemName"]=>
  string(7) "IVAN-PC"
  ["UniqueId"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["UpgradeMethod"]=>
  string(1) "6"
  ["Version"]=>
  string(17) "Modelo 6, nivel 3"
  ["VoltageCaps"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

A partir de ahi puedes hacer lo que quieras, por ejemplo, insertar los valores en una base de datos Mysql.